# Is there a way or tutorial for converting Arduino code to C code?

Tags: c, embedded, arduino

I know that this question is general, but I couldn't find a tutorial or a good coding way to convert Arduino code (I mean the code that we are writing on Arduino software and it doesn't matter for [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) or [Mega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_compatibles#Official_Arduino_versions) or ... ) even if a small sample.

Is there a tutorial?

I just want to learn the technique, and I know that it depends on the project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arduino code *is*, more or less, C code.

The unique things that happen with Arduino is that the code is preprocessed (for example, they give simple hooks by establishing the `setup` and `loop` functions) and has a managed build/upload process that takes care of board limits, includes, libraries, etc...

It is certainly possible to use the same toolkit yourself to build and run the code, that's how I do it. *[Arduino and GCC, compiling and uploading programs using only makefiles](http://www.ashleymills.com/node/327)* is the most useful link I've found covering the steps you need to get started.

As I said, I've left the Arduino IDE and taken up the `avr-gcc` route myself, because if you know the GNU tools, you can do much more powerful things - like use the C++ standard libraries. I missed my `vector`s, what can I say. [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) is lagging quite a bit when it comes to full C++ functionality, making it hard to cram in the [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), but [Andy Brown has gotten much of it working](http://andybrown.me.uk/ws/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/).

Throw those things together and you have quite a powerful development environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer, can I ask you what is your favorite editor for writing this code? and which one is beter to install avr in eclipse and run it from eclips or  using some text editor and run it from terminal?

Comment: @justin I like your question, It will help me alot since I'm really beginner in this area.

Comment: I develop with vim and run the makefiles from the terminal, but now we're getting into some "religious" territory. I think eclipse is a great tool, but configuring it is (imho) every bit as complex as doing it in a terminal, because you're using a GUI to run terminal commands. If you do it in the terminal, it's just a lot closer to a "standard" environment, the one in which the tools were built. It's really about comfort, though: I'm comfortable in the terminal, so it feels more "consistent" to me to work there.

Comment: An advise: never ever use C++ vectors or STL, on a 8-bit MCU outside the hobbyist world. Never mention them on a job interview. Besides the obvious onslaught of the RAM and flash that comes with them, dynamic memory is also frowned upon in the embedded world. If you are looking to become a professional embedded developer, then _don't_ waste time on C++. There are places where the full C++ language can be used, but 8-bit MCUs is not one of them. You have to strip away most of the things that make C++ different from C to make it useful. Focus on C, assembler, electronics, RTOS etc instead.

Comment: Arduino compiles code as C++ and the libraries it provides to simplify coding are based around (C++) classes. Porting these libraries to C would be a big task.

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch Ok. Then it is probably a bad platform to learn professional embedded programming on, as you will pick up bad habits that you must unlearn when going professional. On a 32-bitter with more resources, it would perhaps have been a different matter.

Comment: @Lundin You're right. Arduino exists so that someone doesn't need to learn professional embedded programming. It is designed to be a quick prototyping platform and accessible by people with little to no programming background. On the other hand it provides an easy way into the embedded world so isn't necessarily a bad way to start off...

Comment: Professionals tend to use C and assembly - but this isn't because C++ isn't useful. C++ is perfectly useful, even in the 8 bit world: I used boost::mpl::for_each on my atmega328p to unroll a loop - template metaprogramming is _the most advanced_ feature of C++ - and got a 5x speed boost with cleaner code. The reason C and assembly are used pro is because it's the least _resource intensive_ solution. When one is shipping a million embedded devices, that 15 cents price difference between two chips is worth 150 thousand dollars. When you plan to ship only one, use the best tools you can.

Comment: @Lundin:  You are being rather too  "absolute" in your assertions regarding C++ and dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems. Very little of what you have said is true in all cases, and to be so absolute about it is just bad advice.  Not all embedded systems are either resource constrained, or real-time.  You need to qualify your statements.  The biggest issue with C++ on an 8 bit target is not the suitability of language, but rather the availability of high quality compilers.

Comment: @Clifford I'm absolutely sure that 100% of what I said is true for 8-bit micro-controllers, which was the case here. Things like virtual inheritance, templates and dynamic memory, exceptions shouldn't be used. You would end up with something very similar to [EC++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EC%2B%2B). What you really got to ask yourself is 1) why do you _need_ C++ on a small 8-bit MCU and  2) why did you pick a 8-bit MCU for instead of one of the a mainstream 32-bit? You will most likely find that the answers to those two questions conflict with each other.

Comment: @Lundin:  No, what you said was *your opinion*; that makes it neither try nor false - its is a matter of opinion.  I merely suggested that you were being too black and white about this.  There is always a spectrum of targets and applications that make such decisions more fuzzy.

Comment: @Lundin: An ATmega2560 (16MHz part) is about $10 in quantity 100.  An ATmega328 is about $1.50.  That's why someone would pick a tiny MCU instead of a larger one.  I'm getting ready to design a product that I =must= be able to manufacture for under $10 for it to be a commercial success.  That just ruled out the ATmega2560.  80MHz PIC32 processors are in the $5 price range at quantity 100.  My PCB budget is around $3.  That doesn't leave much room for anything else.

So ... ATmega328 it is.

Answer (score 10):

*(Edit: I missed the very useful link in Matt's answer while writing my own answer. So let's say that what is below is a non technical summary of the link).*

Matt answered right. I would like to add additional information.

The key to understand Arduino programming is in the directory `Arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino`

You will find the `main.cpp` file containing:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int main(void)
{
    init();

    #if defined(USBCON)
        USB.attach();
    #endif

    setup();

    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Do "setup()" and "loop()" (and even "serialEventRun() if you read the Arduino documentation) ring a bell? :-)

Arduino hides only that.

Arduino uses the C++ language. Of course, you can use C if you compile your code yourself with avr-gcc, but the way the Arduino IDE is configured, it is pure C++.

However, as microcontrollers are not really adapted to object-oriented development, some features are missing. I think about the "new" and "delete" operators. They do not exist, so out of the box, you should avoid using the heap when you develop with Arduino. It is why you should be careful if you want to use some standard C++ libraries. They may not be adapted for microcontroller programming (too many memory operations).

In the `Arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino` directory, you can also see the implementation of the Arduino library. It allows watching which "low-level" microcontroller functions (from avr-libc) exist and how you can implement your own libraries and tools.

By the way, as you wanted to know how you could port Arduino code in C, avr-libc is a C library and not a C++ one. So you can see how Arduino wraps its C++ code over C code.

In the `File/Preferences` menu, you can check "see verbose output" to see which parameters and files are used to build the final Arduino binary (and where the temporary build directory is).

Finally, you must also know that Arduino boards have a bootloader embedded with your code. It eases the deployment from the Arduino IDE to the Arduino board. So the Arduino board actually contains more code than your own.

Comment: Object-oriented programming has nothing to do with dynamic memory allocation. It doesn't even have anything to do with the picked programming language. Some languages merely have support for object-oriented features. I write object-oriented programs for microcontrollers, in C, without dynamic memory, all the time.

Comment: That is why I wrote to avoid using the heap, which is not in contradiction in doing OOP. Besides, the Arduino library is a clear example of doing object oriented programming with little or no dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Yes, you can write object oriented code that doesn't perform dynamic memory allocation, but the features that tend to use dynamic memory are key concepts in object oriented languages.  While an experienced programmer isn't going to have their skills stunted by avoiding all of the features that make C++, Java and other OO languages useful, for someone who's just starting out in the embedded world, sticking with plain vanilla C is likely a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a conversion tutorial but a very nice write up about what's behind arduino's hello world:
[A tour of the Arduino internals.  How does hello world actually work?](http://urbanhonking.com/ideasfordozens/2009/05/18/an_tour_of_the_arduino_interna/)